# How to concatenate two integers in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

How do I **concatenate** two **integer** numbers (for example: **10** and **20**) in Kotlin to get a returned value of **1020**?

Comment: That's not really *concatenating*, you could do e.g `a * 100 + b`.

Comment: Should 1020 be a string or an integer?

Comment: @Twistleton Integer

Comment: @ShahabRauf Will the second number always be in the range 10–99?  If so, then multiplying and adding looks best.  But if not, I'm curious as to why you need to do this with integers, when it looks more like string manipulation; converting them to strings and then back to integers would be a code smell, as well as creating temporary objects.

Comment: @gidds I have a scenario where I need to concatenate integers to make item unique but converting every integer to string and then converting it back to integer looks odd to me so I was just looking other solutions.

Comment: @ShahabRauf To avoid strings, you'd have to multiply the first by a power of 10, and add.  But in general, establishing _which_ power of 10 isn't trivial.  You could probably do it with a loop (multiplying a value by 10 each time and comparing), or using the [log10()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.math/log10.html) function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this without Strings, you can calculate the size of the second number in powers of ten, multiply that by the first number, and then add them.

Watch out for maximum integer size.

```
fun combine(x: Int, y: Int): Int {
    var xScale = 1
    while (xScale <= y) {
        xScale *= 10
    }
    return x * xScale + y
}
```

Comment: Oops, sorry @Gidds. I wrote this before looking at your comments and see you already suggested it.

Comment: Works for me. https://pl.kotl.in/mufEPhgZl

Comment: I think it goes without saying there's a limit to integer size, but doing straight math like this won't throw an exception, it will just overflow. It would be more complicated to make sure you don't surpass MAX_VALUE. Maybe sum the digit counts to make sure they are no more than 10 and then start checking the digits of the first number to make sure it won't exceed the digit values of MAX_VALUE's digits.

Answer (score 3):

```
val a: Int = 10
val b: Int = 20

val total: Int = "$a$b".toInt()
```

Comment: Does not work with negative a or b....

Answer (score 2):

**Int Extension**

```
fun Int.concat(other: Int): Int{
        return "{$this$other}".toInt() // It can throw NumberFormatException
    }
```

**Usage**

```
val a = 10 
val b = 20 

a.concat(b) // throws NumberformatException
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: How is this code supposed to work if it always throws a Exception?

Comment: Remove the extra parenthesis to avoid the exception.>>>>>>>>>                                     
          return "$this$other".toInt()

Comment: But again It will throw an NumberFormatException, if the result is out for IntRange

Answer (score 0):

```
val a: Int = 10
val b: Int = 20
int total = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(a) + String.valueOf(b))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
* plus() Returns a string obtained by concatenating this string
* with the string representation of the given other object.
* once the ints are concated to string, then we can convert it back to Int
* It can throw an NumberFormatException, if the result is out for IntRange
*/
fun concatInts(first: Int, second: Int): String {
   val text = first.toString().plus(second)
   // second way
   // val text = "$first$second"
   return text.toInt() 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

One possibility for numbers smaller than 10 would be:

```
val a = 10 
val b = 20 

val c = ("$a".padStart(2,'0') + ("$b").padStart(2,'0')).toInt()   // 1020
```

Example for smaller numbers:

```
val a = 1
val b = 5 
val c = ("$a".padStart(2,'0') + ("$b").padStart(2,'0')).toInt()   // 0105
```